Playing video using AVAsset player returns error "Cannot Open"
Im trying to make a cache system so that cache some videos in splash screen to have better user experience specially for first time opening the app
here's what I did in my cache manager
class CacheManager {static let shared = LocalJackpotsCacheManager()

    private let fileManager = FileManager.default
    private let cacheDirectory: URL
    private let databaseURL: URL
    private var db: OpaquePointer?
    
    private init() {
        // Set cacheDirectory to the Documents directory
        cacheDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("VideoCache")
        databaseURL = cacheDirectory.appendingPathComponent("videoCacheMetadata.sqlite")
        
        createCacheDirectoryIfNeeded()
        setupDatabase()
    }
    
    private func createCacheDirectoryIfNeeded() {
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: cacheDirectory.path) {
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(at: cacheDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                print("Failed to create cache directory: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setupDatabase() {
        if sqlite3_open(databaseURL.path, &db) == SQLITE_OK {
            let createTableQuery = """
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VideoCache (
                id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
                path TEXT,
                lastAccessed INTEGER
            );
            """
            if sqlite3_exec(db, createTableQuery, nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
                print("Failed to create VideoCache table")
            }
        } else {
            print("Unable to open database")
        }
    }
    
    func cacheVideo(from url: URL, forKey key: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let hashedKey = key.sha256()
        let destinationURL = cacheDirectory.appendingPathComponent(hashedKey)
        
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path) {
            completion() // File already cached
            return
        }
        
        let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { tempURL, _, error in
            guard let tempURL = tempURL, error == nil else {
                print("Download error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                completion()
                return
            }
            
            do {
                try self.fileManager.moveItem(at: tempURL, to: destinationURL)
                self.updateDatabase(with: hashedKey, filePath: destinationURL.path)
                completion() // Call completion on success
            } catch {
                print("Error saving video to cache: \(error)")
                completion()
            }
        }
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
    
    func getCachedURL(forKey key: String) -> URL? {
        let hashedKey = key.sha256()
        let fileURL = cacheDirectory.appendingPathComponent(hashedKey)
        return fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) ? fileURL : nil
    }
    
    private func updateDatabase(with key: String, filePath: String) {
        let updateQuery = """
        INSERT OR REPLACE INTO VideoCache (id, path, lastAccessed) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
        """
        var statement: OpaquePointer?
        
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, updateQuery, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            let timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, key, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, filePath, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 3, Int32(timestamp))
            sqlite3_step(statement)
        } else {
            print("Error preparing update statement")
        }
        
        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    }
    
    func cleanOldCache(limit: Int) {
        let selectOldItemsQuery = """
        SELECT id, path FROM VideoCache ORDER BY lastAccessed ASC LIMIT ?;
        """
        var selectStatement: OpaquePointer?
        
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, selectOldItemsQuery, -1, &selectStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_int(selectStatement, 1, Int32(limit))
            
            while sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {
                let id = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 0))
                let path = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1))
                
                // Delete the file from disk
                do {
                    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: path)
                } catch {
                    print("Error deleting file from disk: \(error)")
                }
                
                // Remove from database
                deleteCacheEntry(withId: id)
            }
        }
        
        sqlite3_finalize(selectStatement)
    }
    
    private func deleteCacheEntry(withId id: String) {
        let deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM VideoCache WHERE id = ?;"
        var deleteStatement: OpaquePointer?
        
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteQuery, -1, &deleteStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_text(deleteStatement, 1, id, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_step(deleteStatement)
        } else {
            print("Error preparing delete statement")
        }
        
        sqlite3_finalize(deleteStatement)
    }

}

and how Im trying to use it
 if let cachedFileURL = LocalJackpotsCacheManager.shared.getCachedURL(forKey: cacheKey) {
                        // Log cached file details for confirmation
                        do {
                            let data = try Data(contentsOf: cachedFileURL)
                            print("Cached file successfully loaded into Data object, size: \(data.count) bytes")
                        } catch {
                            print("Failed to load cached file into Data object: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                        // Prepare the video for playback
                        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: cachedFileURL, options: [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: true])
                        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
                        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                        
                        // Configure the cell with the player
                        cell.configure(with: player)
                        player.play() // Start playback immediately if desired
                        
                    } else {
                        // If file is not cached, download and cache it
                        LocalJackpotsCacheManager.shared.cacheVideo(from: videoURL, forKey: cacheKey) {
                            if let cachedFileURL = LocalJackpotsCacheManager.shared.getCachedURL(forKey: cacheKey) {
                                
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    // Prepare the downloaded video for playback
                                    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: cachedFileURL, options: [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: true])
                                    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
                                    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                                    
                                    cell.configure(with: player)
                                    player.play()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

dk what exactly wrong with this but file loaded and printed it's size ! keep says Cannot open
try to cache and play video from local and keep fails

Can you play video from URL you download? Also you should add mime type of video file (like mp4) to destinationURL, currently I'm seeing that, you just append random string.
